# Collapse overlapping coloums in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, merging-data

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'P1':['ARF5','NaN','NaN'],'P2':['NaN','M6PR','NaN'],'P3':['NaN','NaN','NDUFAF7']})
>>> df
     P1    P2       P3
0  ARF5   NaN      NaN
1   NaN  M6PR      NaN
2   NaN   NaN  NDUFAF7
```

I have been trying to collapse it down to something like this:

```
     C1
0  ARF5  
1  M6PR
2  NDUFAF7
```

All columns have an overlap but the degree I do not know. Also I do not know how many columns will be in this df at any iteration since it is part of pipeline of which I need to aggregate my output from.

I think in principle I need the functionality of `combine_first` but for columns.
I tried something like this:

```
df['condensed'] = reduce(lambda x,y:x.combine_first(y),[df[:]])
```

or

```
df['condensed'] = reduce(lambda x,y:x.combine_first(y),[df['P1'],df['P2'],df['P3']])
```

But I have some issues figuring this out.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: Use `bfill1 and `ffill`, it is usually faster than combine_first : ``df.replace({"NaN": np.nan}).bfill(axis=1).ffill(axis=1).iloc[:, 0]``

Comment: @sammywemmy pls don't post answer as comments

Comment: Please feel to comment if you think the question is wrongly closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `bfill` on `axis=1`:

```
df['C1'] = df.replace('NaN', np.nan).bfill(axis=1)['P1']
```

```
>>> df

     P1    P2       P3       C1
0  ARF5   NaN      NaN     ARF5
1   NaN  M6PR      NaN     M6PR
2   NaN   NaN  NDUFAF7  NDUFAF7
```